# ConversationalRetrievalChain : why not able to make chat history working?

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

I am trying to build a custom GPT chatbox using local vector database in python with the langchain package. Especially, I would like to include chat history. I have read several websites (i.a. [ex. 1](https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/question_answering/) and [ex. 2](https://betterprogramming.pub/building-a-multi-document-reader-and-chatbot-with-langchain-and-chatgpt-d1864d47e339#fafe)) and wrote the following code. But unfortunately, it does not work : when, after some questions, I ask "what was the previous question ?", it replies that it does not have access to chat history. It is also unable to rephrase previous part of the chat.

Could anyone pinpoint what is wrong in my code ? I've just spent several hours on that and start becoming a bit despaired... The numerous SO questions I've read so far did not help to solve my issue...

```
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory

client = OpenAI(api_key="sk-...")

# Load from local storage
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
vectordb = FAISS.load_local("path_to_my_vector_DB", embeddings)
 
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", output_key='answer', return_messages=True)

CONDENSE_QUESTION_PROMPT = PromptTemplate.from_template("""
Use the following pieces of context and chat history to answer the 
question at the end.
If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know, 
don't try to make up an answer.
Chat history: {chat_history}\n\nQuestion: {question} 
inputVariables: [ "question", "chat_history"]
""")

pdf_qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.9, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo"),
    vectordb.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'k': 6}),return_source_documents=True,  condense_question_prompt=CONDENSE_QUESTION_PROMPT, memory=memory,verbose=False)

chat_history = []
print('ask your questions\'')
while True:
    query = input("\n*** question: ")
    if query == "stop":
        print('END')
        sys.exit()
    if query == '':
        continue
    result = pdf_qa(
        {"question": query, "chat_history": chat_history})
    print("> Answer: " + result["answer"])
    chat_history.append((query, result["answer"]))
```